# how to get xml file from google rss

Tags: rss

let's say I want to get the xml file from google rss for Apple. I am pretty new to RSS and XML so I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: SuperString are you talking about getting the file programmatically?  If so, which language?  If not this question should be closed as NPR or even NARQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) *is* XML. So if you have the RSS feed for Apple, you have the XML file.

Comment: yea I know that. I just don't know how I would download the file manually and then automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you have to follow the rss link, it is the link to the xml file. In some circumstances, it would be necessary to use AJAX download techniques, it depends on the situation the code works (js in a browser, standalone network-connected app, http or ftp download and so on)